# how to run $(window).load() even if something on the page fails to load

Tags: jquery

I'm using `$(window).load()` to re-size the minimum height of a text field based on various other heights that change on page load. My script works fine, however, if another script on the page fails to load (for some unknown reason) the `$(window).load()` doesn't run.

Is there a way to get the `$(window).load()` to run even if an error has occurred (maybe using `.error()`), i.e. bypass the errored script?

my current script for the `load()` event is below if this helps:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
var imageArea = $('.imageArea').height();
var productDetail = $('.productDetail').height();
var productText = (imageArea - productDetail) - 110; //-110 is the height of another element
$('.productText').css('min-height', productText);
});
```

Comment: did you try "pageLoad" function ?

Comment: Errors are not something you should ignore in javascript, fix the source of the error rather than ignore it

Comment: @Esailija - I would only the script is external and I don't have access to it to fix the problem. I've spoken to dev team who's script it is so they can look in to fixing it there end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try :

```
window.onerror = function(){
    var imageArea = $('.imageArea').height();
    var productDetail = $('.productDetail').height();
    var productText = (imageArea - productDetail) - 110; //-110 is the height of another element
    $('.productText').css('min-height', productText);
}
```

wishing jQuery is loaded…

Comment: Would I run this script as well as my one in case of an error or would this work even if there's no error?

Comment: `window.onerror` is launched only if and when there's an error in js (or when you trigger it). so you need both.

Comment: Thought so, that looks like it should work. I'll try now - I don't suppose there's a way of combining the two?

Comment: You can factorize. Make a function with those 4 lines & put it in your event and the onerror one

Comment: Cool, I've done that and applied it to my page but it's still not running the script if the other script fails. Looking at it, it looks like the other script fails to run properly but doesn't bring up any errors in the element inspector (which will be why the `.onerror` doesn't work. I think I'm going to have to just get this external script fixed to get it all to work. Thanks for the help though, your answer would have been correct if an error appeared I reckon so I've accepted it.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using media queries in your CSS and the meta viewport tag in your code if you want your page responsive.

For your image you could add this to your CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Some browsers need more help:

```
@media \0screen {
  img { 
    width: auto; /* for ie 8 */
  }
}
```

---

Other articles:

- [Different background image depending on screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699442/different-background-image-depending-on-screen-resolution)

Similar to this for a background image:

```
@media (min-width:800px) { background-image: url(bg-800.jpg) }
@media (min-width:1024px) { background-image: url(bg-1024.jpg) }
@media (min-width:1280px) { background-image: url(bg-1280.jpg) }
```

Comment: My changing heights are dependent on dynamic content not window size unfortunately. Most, if not all other page elements are fixed width and height meaning a whole overhaul to make the whole page responsive. A definite change for the future though.

Comment: Agreed. I just did on my site: http://www.goomzee.com a couple months ago and reworking back end of some products too.  It's good for catch-all but not the best for mobile only so we do both.  Hopefully that helped a bit and if I think of anything else I'll update post.